# Runtime error "SIGCONT" while finding lapindromes using c++

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve lapindrome problem on codechef.

On my local ide the program ran as expected.

But while in codechef submission it is giving runtime error "SIGCONT".

```
#include<iostream>
#pragma GCC optimize("Ofast")
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    do
    {
        string l;
        cin>>l;
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (l.length()/2); i++)
        {
            if (l[i] == l[i+(l.length()/2)])
            {
                c++;
            }

        }
        if (c == l.length()/2) {
            printf("YES\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("NO\n");
        }
        t--;
    } while (t!=0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SIGCONT` is not an error, it is used for job control in Unix. This looks like a codechef bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I would like to point out that your code is wrong because for the test case ***rotor*** your code is giving ***NO*** as an answer, it should be ***YES***.

**Why getting the wrong answer?**

In question it is given, *if there are odd number of characters in the string, we ignore the middle character and check for lapindrome.*

So, you need to modify/delete the below code.

```
if (c == l.length()/2) {
            printf("YES\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("NO\n");
        }
```

and instead do this:

```
if (c == l.length()/2) {
                //check for lapindrome
            }
            else
            {
               //remove middle character
               //check for lapindrome
            }
```

**Why "SIGCONT" error?**

This error occurs when you ***exceed the IDE's printing limit***. For Codechef IDE, it’s around 2^16 Characters.

You can try printing the output directly in a file locally. (Thanks to black_truce for this).

**My Code:**

You can check below solution for reference.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        string str,str1,str2;
        cin>>str;
        int len=str.length();
        if(len%2==0){
           str1=str.substr(0, len/2);
           str2=str.substr(len/2, len);
        }
        else{
            str1=str.substr(0, len/2);
            str2=str.substr(len/2+1, len);
        }
        sort(str1.begin(), str1.end());
        sort(str2.begin(), str2.end());
        if(str1==str2) cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        else cout<<"NO"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```